# How to convert System.Drawing.Font into Itextsharp Basefont

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio, itext

I want to get the font of a textbox into itextsharp basefont in winform c#.
I also want to align the text in a PDF according to alignment of the textbox in winform.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow :) What have you tried so far?

Comment: I want to make basefont dynamic (not fixed font name , font size,bold, italics, underline) according to winform textbox font. I don't know how to perform this operation.

Answer (score 3):

Use `FontFactory.RegisterDirectories()` to read your fonts. Get the font name from `System.Drawing.Font` and call `FontFactory.GetFont()` with that name.

Comment: example please that would be niec

Answer (score 0):

You can use `iTextSharp.text.Font` instead as the following:

```
Font font = FontFactory.GetFont("Segoe UI", 18.0f, BaseColor.Black);
```

if you have `System.Drawing.Font` use the following:

```
System.Drawing.Font systemDrawingFont = new System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI", 12);
Font font = FontFactory.GetFont(systemDrawingFont.Name, systemDrawingFont.Size, BaseColor.Black);
```